# Sending messages to a local queue on a queue manager that is fronted by another queue manager

Tags: ibm-mq

Would need advice on the following scenario (for my personal learning):

Setup is as follows: QM1 -> QM2 -> QM3

QM1 - 1 alias queue (that will put message to the remote queue), 1 remote queue (destined for QM2's local queue), 1 transmission queue (to QM2) and 1 sender channel to QM2
QREMOTE DEFN as follows:

```
DEFINE QREMOTE('QM1.RQ1') RQMNAME('QM2') RNAME('QM2.LQ1') XMITQ('QM2') DEFPSIST(YES)
```

QM2 - 1 local queue (to receive message from QM1), 1 transmission queue (to QM3), 1 receiver channel from QM1 and 1 sender channel to QM3

QM3 - 1 local queue (to receive messages) and 1 receiver channel (between QM2 and QM3)

Note: QM1 and QM2 are connected, QM2 and QM3 are connected, but messages from QM1 to QM3 needs to be passed through QM2 to reach the local queue on QM3.

Question: Without modifying any settings on QM2 and QM3, what to configure on QM1 in order to send message to QM3's local queue from QM1?

Comment: Change the Remote queue definition to point to QM3 instead of QM2. Add your QREMOTE definition to the question, and I can make an example command to match.

Comment: @MoragHughson Hi Morag, thanks for your comment. However, I am looking at a solution such that the messages goes from QM1>QM2>QM3 instead of QM1>QM3, and the changes I can make is only to QM1. QM1 and QM3 is only connected via QM2. 
QREMOTE DEFN as follows: DEFINE QREMOTE('QM1.RQ1') RQMNAME('QM2') RNAME('QM2.LQ1') XMITQ('QM2') DEFPSIST(YES)

Comment: See my answer - you will still be going via QM2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your QREMOTE as follows:-

```
ALTER QREMOTE('QM1.RQ1') RQMNAME('QM3') RNAME('QM3.LQ1') XMITQ('QM2')
```

As you can see, the message put to this queue still goes on the `QM2` transmission queue and when it is moved by the SDR/RCVR channel over as far as QM2, the RCVR channel will do an MQPUT to queue=QM3.LQ1 on qmgr=QM3 and this will then resolve the message to be placed onto the `QM3` transmission queue, where the next SDR/RCVR channel will move it to QM3.